# Android Graph with multiple Y axis

Tags: android

I have to implement a graph with two y axis, and also need to customize the two y axis ,x axis and their scales and labels and need to plot points against one of the y axis and adjust the scale of secondary y axis. Is there any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

[AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html) is the solution. It has support for multiple Y axes.

Screenshot from the demo app:

[image: Multiple scales chart]